# Subquery with Max and Group by

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, max

I'm trying to use a conditional like this:

```
WHERE Table1.Score = 
    (
    SELECT MAX(Table1.Score) 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE Table1.Date >= '2023-03-01'
        GROUP BY Table1.Word
    )
```

**Table1**

| Word | Score | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Faye | 85 | 2023-03-02 |
| Faye | 90 | 2023-03-01 |
| Faye | 80 | 2023-03-03 |
| Jet | 95 | 2023-03-03 |
| Jet | 85 | 2023-03-01 |
| Jet | 90 | 2023-03-01 |
| Jet | 70 | 2023-03-02 |
| Spike | 75 | 2023-03-02 |
| Spike | 85 | 2023-03-02 |
| Toby | 70 | 2023-03-01 |

I'm expecting to receive as result only lines from the table that contain 'word' and max value of 'score'. For example:
All lines that contain Faye and 90; Jet and 96; Spike and 85; Toby and 70.

Comment: You want a correlated subquery kind of `..WHERE t2.Date >= '2023-03-01' and t2.Word=t1.Word..`

Comment: Yes, but the conditional is that the result only bring each distinct variable in Word field with the respective max value in Score field.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply need a ROW_NUMBER window function -

```
SELECT word, Score
  FROM (SELECT Word, Score, Date,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Word ORDER BY Score DESC) RN
          FROM your_table
       ) x
 WHERE RN = 1
```